# What would it mean if the solution to an IVP did not have maximal interval of existence?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I understand that it can be proved that for the IVP:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x)\quad$; $x(0)=x_0$

There is a maximal interval of existence $(\alpha,\beta)$, where there exists a unique solution.

However I do not really understand the concept  of maximal interval of existence. What would it mean if the solution did not have a maximal interval of existence?

Comment: A maximal interval of existence must exist. Do you know the definition of *maximal*?

Comment: I get that if a solution exist on $(-1000,+1000)$ it also exists on e.g $(-3,2)$, but $(-1000,+1000)$ is the 'biggest'(maximal) interval it exists on.